# JavaScript Выдача правильного ответа рандомного выражения среди рандомных неправильных

Tags: javascript

Задача: нужно, чтобы ответ на выражение появлялся среди кнопок с вариантами ответа и при нажатии выдавал correct.

Я привязала нажимаемую кнопку к переменной, в которой выводится значение суммы. Далее я прописала, чтобы в трёх кнопках появлялись рандомные цифры, и если среди них появится значение суммы, будет correct. Но я не знаю, как сделать так, чтобы в рандоме чисел на кнопках обязательно был ответ на выражение. К тому же, мне кажется, что сейчас даже если числа на кнопке совпадут, correct не выйдет. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как мне реализовать задуманное.

```js
var numbers = generateRandomNumbers(3);

var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
let numberDisplayFirst = document.querySelector("#numberdisplayfirst");
let numberDisplaySecond = document.querySelector("#numberdisplaysecond");
let amountDisplay = document.getElementById("amountDisplay");

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

let firstNumber = getRandomInt(1, 10);
let secondNumber = getRandomInt(1, 10);
var sumNumbers = firstNumber * secondNumber;

numberDisplayFirst.textContent = firstNumber;
numberDisplaySecond.textContent = secondNumber;
amountDisplay.textContent = sumNumbers;

for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    squares[i].textContent = numbers[i]
    squares[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        var clickedNumber = this.textContent;
        if(clickedNumber === sumNumbers){
            alert("correct");
        } else {
            alert("wrong");//игра заканчивается
        }
    })
}

function generateRandomNumbers(num) {
    var arr=[]
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++){
    arr.push(randomNumbers());    
    }
    return arr;
}

function randomNumbers(){
    var first = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
    return "" + first;
}

function sumNumbers(){
    var sumNumbers = Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length);
    return numbers[sumNumbers];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Игра на знание таблицы уравнений</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><span id="numberdisplayfirst"></span>
         x 
         <span id="numberdisplaysecond"></span>
          = 
          <span id="amountDisplay"></span></h1>
        <div id="container">
            <button class="square"></button>    
            <button class="square"></button>
            <button class="square"></button>
        </div>
        <script src="Index.js"></script>    
    </body>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Но я не знаю, как сделать так, чтобы в рандоме чисел на кнопках
>   обязательно был ответ на выражение.

Переменную numbers нужно заполнять изначально не тремя, а двумя значениями (N-1, где N - кол-во кнопок), а затем добавлять в массив правильный ответ и перемешивать массив.

> К тому же, мне кажется, что сейчас даже если числа на кнопке совпадут,
>   correct не выйдет.

Так и есть, ошибка в условии, смотрите верный код ниже с комментариями.

Код:

```js
var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");

// не 3, а 2 элемента заполняем
var numbers = generateRandomNumbers(squares.length - 1); 

let numberDisplayFirst = document.querySelector("#numberdisplayfirst");
let numberDisplaySecond = document.querySelector("#numberdisplaysecond");
let amountDisplay = document.getElementById("amountDisplay");

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

let firstNumber = getRandomInt(1, 10);
let secondNumber = getRandomInt(1, 10);
var sumNumbers = firstNumber * secondNumber;

numberDisplayFirst.textContent = firstNumber;
numberDisplaySecond.textContent = secondNumber;
amountDisplay.textContent = sumNumbers;

// добавляем в массив третий элемент = правильный ответ
numbers.push(sumNumbers);
// перемешиваем массив
numbers.sort(function(){ return Math.random() - 0.5 });

for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
  squares[i].textContent = numbers[i]
  squares[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var clickedNumber = this.textContent;
    /*
      у вас было === - строгое равенство, но типы разные, поэтому оно не будет срабатывать 
      будет работать при нестрогом равенстве, как ниже исправлено,
      или если приводить к одному типу, например, if (parseInt(clickedNumber) === parseInt(sumNumbers)) {
    */
    if (clickedNumber == sumNumbers) {
      alert("correct");
    } else {
      alert("wrong"); //игра заканчивается
    }
  })
}

function generateRandomNumbers(num) {
  var arr = []
  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    arr.push(randomNumbers());
  }
  return arr;
}

function randomNumbers() {
  var first = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
  return "" + first;
}

function sumNumbers() {
  var sumNumbers = Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length);
  return numbers[sumNumbers];
}
```

```html
<h1><span id="numberdisplayfirst"></span> x
  <span id="numberdisplaysecond"></span> =
  <span id="amountDisplay"></span></h1>
<div id="container">
  <button class="square"></button>
  <button class="square"></button>
  <button class="square"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое :)

Comment: @АннаЧередниченко если мой ответ решил ваш вопрос, отметьте ответ галочкой, как решение, спасибо.